# Invisible magic components that spoil the Eagle preview

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

You know, after the eagle board design is finished, you can see the card on the preview screen.

I'll show you two examples. There is no problem with one. The card is centered on the preview screen.

But in the other, the card is not centered because of the components that are not visible in the upper right sections. I cannot zoom in on the card. As if the eagle is showing me something very big.

I tried these but didn't work:

1- I open all layers from the Layer tab. Nothing is visible.

2 - I am trying to delete that space by selecting it with a mouse. Nothing is caught.

3 - I saved the design as a desing block and included it in the new project. Nothing changed.

Does anyone have an idea?  Btw, the same is true for the manufacturing tab.

[image: this is normal]

[image: this is not centered.]

[image: It is also not centered in the manufacturing tab.]

Comment: Does Eagle let you export a netlist and re-import?  If so, examine it in a text editor.

Comment: Try changing the background colour to black to see if white objects show up.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for reply. Actuallay I alreay use black background. And I make the background white. nothing happen. Still nothing is visible.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Sorry, I do not fully understand what you are saying. I guess you're talking about something I don't know. Can you open a little more? Maybe if there is a document or resource, I can read it.

Comment: Is there anything on any of the hidden layers? Try running `display all` and seeing if anything is up there.